# Sending large data to wcf service returns me "504 (Gateway Time-out) error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am trying to describe my problem detailed. Our aim is sending objects to wcf service which is processed and respond with another object. If we send 1000, 2000 object, we have a successful result. But when we increase the size of object like 10.000, 20.000 the server waited 1-1.30 minutes then responded 504 gateway error. 
Firstly, on client side, we upload a file then read it to the server side. We initialize object of reading data and send this object to service. My controller like:

```
public ActionResult SaleNotification(NOTIFICATION_OBJECT notificationItem, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{

    if (files != null)
    {
        List<NOTIFICATION_ITEM_OBJECT> fileItems = new List<NOTIFICATION_ITEM_OBJECT>();
        using (var package = new StreamReader(files.InputStream))
        {
            package.ReadLine();
            while (!package.EndOfStream)
            {

                var values = package.ReadLine().Split(';');
                if (values[0] != "" && values[1] != "" && values[2] != "" && values[3] != "")
                {
                    fileItems.Add(new NOTIFICATION_ITEM_OBJECT
                    {
                        GT = values[0],
                        SN = values[1].ToUpper(),
                        BN = values[2].ToUpper(),
                        XD = values[3]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        notificationItem.NOTIFICATION_ITEMS.AddRange(fileItems);
    }
    var res = _serviceRepository.SendNotification(Security.Decrypt(SERVICE_PASS_ENCRYPT, true), notificationItem);
    return PartialView("PartialResult", res);

}
```

Sending notification to service part, I tried to send the whole object at one time maybe that part my approach was wrong. Here is my code:

```
    public NOTIFICATION_RESULT_OBJECT SendNotification( string password, NOTIFICATION_OBJECT notification)
    {
        var res = new NOTIFICATION_RESULT_OBJECT();
        try
        {
            var client = new serviceClient();
            if (client.ClientCredentials != null)
            {
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;        
            }

            using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                #region header
                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();   
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
                #endregion

               //Some codes service request initialize

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                var response = client.notify(serviceRequest);

                res.NOTIFICATION_ID = response.NOTIFICATIONID;
                foreach (var item in response)
                    res.PRODUCT_RESULT_LIST.Add(new PRODUCT_RESULT()
                    {
                        GT = item.GT,
                        RC = item.RC,
                        SN = item.SN,
                        BN = item.BN,
                        XD = item.XD.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("tr-TR")),
                    });
                return res;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log4NetFunction.InsertLog(ex);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a configuration on my bindings about maxReceivedMessageSize, sendTimeout, receivedTimeout etc. Here is an example of one of my bindings:

```
<binding name="serviceBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  openTimeout="00:10:00" 
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

In my debug I couldn't find any error it send 20000 object successful on locally or there is no log about this error on server. So I couldn't find any solution. How can I solve this problem? Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your service refuses to serialize the data with so many data members.

Please try to set the readerQuotas property of your binding.

```
<binding  allowCookies="false"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"   openTimeout="00:10:00" 
         closeTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"  >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This error happens because of waiting too long to get an answer. I decided to use different methodology to solve it. But also adding readerQuotas is helped to send message.